# How to dynamically move a divider/splitted between 2 layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts in the same xml file(top layout and bottom bottom layout). I want the user to be able to grab the edge of that separates them and be able to move it up or down sizing the layouts accordingly. Kinda like a sliding door but it starts from the middle and can go top or bottom to where the touch is released
How do you say I can do this? Can I implement an on touch listener on the edge of layout or is there a better way?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that I would do this is to have a View between the two Layouts. The Layouts would have as an example:

```
<LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="0dip" 
           android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
      <View android:id="@+id/layout_draggable"
           android:layout_height="10dip" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"  />
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="0dip" 
           android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You would then have a touch listener on the middle View, which would alter the weighting for the two layouts. The floats must add up to 1, and doing so will make the draggable View move as well.

Comment: Ohthis is a very good suggestion Thank you. My question is, when somone touches a view so my touch listner would move the draggable view to whereever the touch is going  correct? If thats the case how can I adjust the weights accordingly. Or would they adjust automatically depending where  I am placing the view? Thanks

Comment: You would need to adjust the weights yourself according to a self-made algorithm. I would use an onTouchEvent listener and get the amount that the user has dragged, determine the height of the parent LinearLayout and create a 0.0-1.0 value from that.